# Outsourcing functions in PHP

Tags: php, function, class

I'm at a point where my classes get really really big. Now my question is:

Is there any good way of outsourcing functions? So, that this

foo.php

```
class Foo
{
    function sample()
    {
        echo "Hello";
    }

    function bar()
    {
        echo " World!";
    }
}
```

will be splitted up to 3 files or something like that? Like 1 file for the class and 2 for the functions. What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Put all your class code in one file.

Comment: Thats what im doing for the whole time now, but i get tired scrolling through 3000 lines of code all the time, thats why i want to oursource

Comment: Use an editor that gives you features like search, introspection/indexing of methods, bookmarks, etc.  There are numerous intelligent PHP aware editors you can choose from.

Comment: When a class becomes too large (and 3000 lines is definitely too large) this is a sign that it does too much. Inspect the responsibilities of the class and break it in smaller classes.

Comment: to shrink the size of a class, delegate more of its responsibilities to other parts of the codebase.

Comment: You really, really, need to take a look in [Design Principles](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod), [Refactoring](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring) and [Object Calisthenics](http://williamdurand.fr/2013/06/03/object-calisthenics/).

Answer (score 1):

you could use trait

1.php

```
require_once('2.php');
class Foo
    {
      use outsourcedfunctions; 
    }
```

2.php

```
trait outsourcedfunctions
{
  function sample()
  {
    echo "Hello";
  }

  function bar()
  {
    echo " World!";
  }
```